# Concatenate all non numeric strings in String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array like this

```
    String str="9790020760001613 JOHN MATHEWS          -66822.60        65000.00        69000.00        -1822.60  KARL MAX";
    String[] token = str.split("\\s+");
```

I wanted to concatenate all the non numeric tokens(e.g JOHN MATHEWS )  till a non numeric token is immediately followed by numeric string so that above token String array would look like this:

```
[9790020760001613 ,JOHN MATHEWS,-66822.60,65000.00,69000.00,-1822.60,KARL MAX]
```

Comment: `till a non numeric token is immediately followed by numeric string`. How does KARL MAX satisfy this condition? There are no numeric strings after KARL MAX

Comment: We can make another check if there is no numeric string after that token (MAX)

Comment: Are you sure your string is not tab-delimited? If it is, then the names are probably in the same field.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes i am sure they john and mathews reside at different index positions

Comment: @WasimWani Well, we could do a lot of things if you mention the requirements correctly. I don't see your question explicitly mentioning this requirement.

Comment: Of course they are in different index positions. The question is whether the delimiter is space or tab. What is the source of this string? Can you check the value of the character immediately after the numeric string?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Delimiter is definitely a space.

Comment: This piece of code will test a string for numeric or non numeric

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
 {  
   try  
   {  
     double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
   }  
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
   {  
     return false;  
   }  
   return true;  
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matcher is fine:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:-)?([0-9]+(?:\\.)?[0-9]+))|([A-Z]([A-Z/]|\\s)+[A-Z])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("9790020760001613 JOHN MATHEWS S/O          -66822.60        65000.00        69000.00        -1822.60  KARL MAX");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches.toArray()));
```

Outputs:

```
[9790020760001613, JOHN MATHEWS S/O, -66822.60, 65000.00, 69000.00, -1822.60, KARL MAX]
```

Could possibly be improved but it works.

Comment: Well it works but if input string contains a charcter like / , it will not gve expeced result. e.g if isntead of JOHN MATHEWS it is JOHN MATHEWS S/O the output would be

[9790020760001613, JOHN MATHEWS S, -66822.60, 65000.00, 69000.00, -1822.60, KARL MAX]

Comment: @WasimWani You didn't provide an example like that, edited the answer.